# Electron window.require is not a function even with nodeIntegration set to true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I've been experiencing some issues with an Electron + Create React App app I'm making. It's an offline app for cost calculation, I need to persist a couple user settings, for this I used https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store. Like with most electron's modules, I have to import it as:

```
const Store = window.require("electron-store");
```

To avoid webpack's conflicts. By searching I found that for most people setting nodeIntegration: true when creating electron's BrowserWindow would avoid the problem, but it's not my case, I keep getting the same error.

What I've already tried:

1. Using plain require: It results in TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function, and in console: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '...\node_modules\write-file-atomic'
2. Use a module to override webpack config: I used craco to set target to electron-renderer. It results in a blank page when I launch the app, with an error in devtools telling ReferenceError: require is not defined

Additional info is that I'm not using typescript but plain js so using "declare global" and such won't work

My public/electron.js file:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 680,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
  if (!isDev) mainWindow.setMenu(null);
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

electron.app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post how you create your `BrowserWindow` including all it's configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have tu create a preoload script on electron.

1. Create a file named preload.js on the directory where you have de electron main script, Put this code on it:

   window.require = require;
2. Go to your electron main script and type this in the code where you create the window:

   win = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 1280,
   height: 720,
   webPreferences: {
   nodeIntegration: false,
   preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
   },

   })
   With this you will preload the script before all, this fixed the problem for me, I hope also for you.

Comment: this is solved the problem to me after 1000 failed attempt

Comment: My electron version is 12.0.0. And preload.js works well but the property that I set in preload.js of window just disappear after window popup. So I can't access the property.

Comment: @neosarchizo You probably need to set `webPreferences.contextIsolation = false`. An alternative that seems like it *should* work (in newer electron versions) is `require("electron").contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("require", require)`, but that didn't actually work when I tried it. (it said `Cannot find module 'XXX'` in renderer; not a good idea anyway to expose the require function in renderer, but wanted to try it)

Answer (score 3):

Electron 12 changed the default setting of `contextIsolation` for webPreferences, as documented in their [breaking changes for Electron 12](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#default-changed-contextisolation-defaults-to-true). Setting it to `false` will allow you access to `require()` again, as per their notes:

> In Electron 12, contextIsolation will be enabled by default. To restore the previous behavior, contextIsolation: false must be specified in WebPreferences.
>
> We recommend having contextIsolation enabled for the security of your application.
>
> Another implication is that require() cannot be used in the renderer process unless nodeIntegration is true and contextIsolation is false.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 900,
  height: 680,
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: false,
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
}
```